# how to join more then two table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, odoo, pgadmin

i am running following query

```
select 
    to_char(sale_order.date_order ,'DD-MM-YYYY') , sum(sale_order.amount_total) as amount

from 
    public.sale_order
where
   sale_order.order_year = '2015' and
   sale_order.order_month = 'April'
group by 
   to_char(sale_order.date_order ,'DD-MM-YYYY') order by to_char(sale_order.date_order ,'DD-MM-YYYY') asc
```

its giving correct output

```
   to_char..     amount

"14-04-2015";   1298.00
"15-04-2015";   4294.00
"16-04-2015";   1398.00
"17-04-2015";   1927.00
"18-04-2015";   3094.00
"19-04-2015";   6988.00
"20-04-2015";   6641.00
"21-04-2015";   3045.00
```

but i am trying to enter a condition which have multiple table connection then it gives different amount value

```
select 
    to_char(sale_order.date_order ,'DD-MM-YYYY') , sum(sale_order.amount_total) as amount

from 
    public.sale_order ,
    public.sale_order_line , 
    public.product_product ,
    public.product_template ,
    public.product_category

where
    sale_order_line.product_id = product_product.id AND
  product_product.product_tmpl_id = product_template.id AND
  product_template.categ_id = product_category.id AND
  sale_order.id = sale_order_line.order_id AND
  sale_order_line.product_id = product_product.id AND 
  product_product.product_tmpl_id = product_template.id AND 
  product_template.categ_id = product_category.id AND
  product_category.name = 'Starchi' and
    sale_order.order_year = '2015' and
  sale_order.order_month = 'April'
group by to_char(sale_order.date_order ,'DD-MM-YYYY') order by to_char(sale_order.date_order ,'DD-MM-YYYY') asc
```

then it gives different output

```
  to_char         amount
"14-04-2015";    1298.00
"15-04-2015";    4294.00
"16-04-2015";    1398.00
"17-04-2015";    2805.00     //wrong output
"18-04-2015";    6188.00    //wrong output
"19-04-2015";    13976.00  //wrong output
"20-04-2015";    19229.00  //wrong output
"21-04-2015";    3045.00
```

what is the exact problem please anybody can tell ?

and how to solve it ?

Comment: The problem is that your joins are multiplying the number of rows.  Postgres is working fine.  The issue is either your data or your understanding of the data.

Comment: how i can solve this it may adding row of sale_order and sale_order_line

Comment: I would start by rewriting the query to join-syntax. And then: comment out all the unused tables(in particular: `order_line`) . Plus: there is no need to aggregate on `to_char()`, aggregation on the raw date_order will work just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[USING @Patrick 's cleaned up code] Most probable cause is that an 1:N relation exists between orders and order_lines, causing the orders with multiple order_lines to be included in the sum() more than once.

```
SELECT to_char(o.date_order, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS date_order
        , sum(o.amount_total) AS amount
FROM public.sale_order o
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
        -- These tables probably have an N:1 relation
        -- to public.sale_order
        -- We don't have to sum them; just check existence.
        FROM public.sale_order_line l
        JOIN public.product_product pp ON pp.id = l.product_id
        JOIN public.product_template pt ON pt.id = pp.product_tmpl_id
        JOIN public.product_category pc ON pc.id = pt.categ_id
        WHERE pc.name = 'Starchi'
        AND l.order_id = o.id
        )
  AND o.order_year = '2015'
  AND o.order_month = 'April'
GROUP BY o.date_order
ORDER BY o.date_order ASC
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in your `WHERE` clauses, as Gordon Linoff already commented, leading to duplicate rows being retrieved and then summed up to give wrong totals. Following wildplasser's advice in his comment, using the `JOIN` syntax is much cleaner and less error-prone. Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT to_char(o.date_order, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS "date", sum(o.amount_total) AS amount
FROM public.sale_order o
JOIN public.sale_order_line l ON l.order_id = o.id
JOIN public.product_product pp ON pp.id = l.product_id
JOIN public.product_template pt ON pt.id = pp.product_tmpl_id
JOIN public.product_category pc ON pc.id = pt.categ_id
WHERE pc.name = 'Starchi'
  AND o.order_year = '2015'
  AND o.order_month = 'April'
GROUP BY o.date_order
ORDER BY o.date_order ASC
```

Comment: it also gives same output as above define no solution

Comment: That is impossible. Have a closer look at your data 17-20 April because there is a problem there. Edit your question to post the data from 1 or more of these days to get a better answer.